# Code Smith 6: Using Custom Utility

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, codesmith

I have a CodeSmith 6 project setup in Visual Studio.  I added a class with a shared method (VB), but cannot refer to it in my template.  I also tried adding an assembly reference to the project DLL, but that didn't work either.  How can I use my own utilities like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please post a sample of how you are trying to [reference this project dll](http://docs.codesmithtools.com/display/Generator/Referencing+Assemblies) / [code behind](http://docs.codesmithtools.com/display/Generator/Sharing+Common+Code)? I've attached some documentation links on how to accomplish this.